# OpenMP parallel for loop speedup issues

Tags: c++, openmp

Recently I started using OpenMP. Doing a numerical calculation involving 3d matrices created in c++ as vectors and I used parallel for loops to speedup the code. But it runs slower than serial code. I compile the code using Codeblocks in Windows 7. The code is something like this.

```
int main(){
  vector<vector<vector<float> > > Dx; //

/*create 3d array Dx[IE][JE][KE] as vectors*/
  Dx.resize(IE);
  for (int i = 0; i < IE; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < JE; ++j){
      dx[i][j].resize(KE);
    }
  }
  //declare and initialize more matrices like this
  .
  .
  .
  double wtime = omp_get_wtime(); // start time
  //and matrix calculations using parallel for loop 

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i=1; i < IE; ++i ) {
    for (int j=1; j < JE; ++j ) {
      for (int k=1; k < KE; ++k ) {
        curl_h = ( Hz[i][j][k] - Hz[i][j-1][k] - Hy[i][j][k] + Hy[i][j][k-1]);
        idxl[i][j][k] = idxl[i][j][k] + curl_h;
        Dx[i][j][k] = gj3[j]*gk3[k]*dx[i][j][k] 
                    + gj2[j]*gk2[k]*.5*(curl_h + gi1[i]*idxl[i][j][k]);
      }  
    }
  }

  wtime =  omp_get_wtime() - wtime;
}
```

But code with parallel loops run slower than the serial code. Any ideas ? 
Thxs.

Comment: Before you even look at the performance, is the parallel version even producing the correct output?

Comment: What are the matrix dimensions?

Comment: where was `curl_h` defined? If it was outside the for-loops make sure to make it thread-private `#pragma omp parallel for private(curl_h)`

Comment: Defining private(curl_h) does the trick. Now the execution time reduced by half compared with the serial code and they both produce same results. Matrix dimensions are 150x150x150. Thanks for all the response !

Answer (score 0):

The loop uses the variable `curl_h`, which is not declared as thread private. This is both a bug, and also the reason for your perceived performance problem:

As there is only one place in memory where `curl_h` is stored, *all threads constantly and concurrently try to read and write it*. One CPU core will load the value into its cache, the next one will issue a write to it, invalidating the cache of the first CPU, which will again grab the cacheline when it itself tries to use `curl_h` (read or write, both will require the cacheline to be in the local cache).

The point is, that the fierce pretense put up by the hardware that there is only one memory location called `curl_h` demands its tribute. You get a huge amount of chatter in the cache coherency protocol, and keep your memory buses busy with constantly refetching the same cacheline from memory. All your threads are really doing is fighting over that one cacheline.

Of course, the constant races between the threads are a big bug, as no process can be certain that the value it's currently using is actually the one it calculated in the statement above.

So, just add the correct `private()` declarations to your `omp parallel for` statement, and you'll fix both the bug and the performance issue.